# Pileup on bed file from within R

Tags: r, bioinformatics

I have a data table in R which I want to count the number of overlapping windows for. This is essentially a pileup command and seems to be something that could be done using bedtools, but I can't figure out how to do so without leaving R.

Is there an R function to do this already, or any suggestions about what may be an efficient approach?

In case it's helpful, here is a mini example of what I'm trying to do. Thanks in advance!

input:

```
chrom    start     end
1        1         100
1        50        150
```

returns:

```
chrom      start    end    count
1        1          49      1
1        50         100     2
1        101        150     1
```

Comment: Check out the answers here: https://www.biostars.org/p/173502/

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55679894/counting-overlaps-as-expected-with-r-data-table-foverlaps-or-iranges

Comment: Related: [Overlap join with start and end positions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24480031/overlap-join-with-start-and-end-positions), with nice `data.table` answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While most linked answers use `findOverlaps` or similar in `GRanges` context, the easiest approach for me would be to use `coverage`. It is easy to switch back and forth, to pick the framework that is most convenient or efficient.

```r
library(GenomicRanges)

gr <- GRanges(1, IRanges(c(1,50), c(100,150)))
gr.cov <- as(coverage(gr), "GRanges")
gr.cov
#> GRanges object with 3 ranges and 1 metadata column:
#>       seqnames    ranges strand |     score
#>          <Rle> <IRanges>  <Rle> | <integer>
#>   [1]        1      1-49      * |         1
#>   [2]        1    50-100      * |         2
#>   [3]        1   101-150      * |         1
#>   -------
#>   seqinfo: 1 sequence from an unspecified genome

# if you want to have a data.table
DT <- data.table::as.data.table(gr.cov)
DT
#>    seqnames start end width strand score
#> 1:        1     1  49    49      *     1
#> 2:        1    50 100    51      *     2
#> 3:        1   101 150    50      *     1

# convert back to GRanges:
with(DT, GRanges(seqnames, IRanges(start, end), score=score))
#> GRanges object with 3 ranges and 1 metadata column:
#>       seqnames    ranges strand |     score
#>          <Rle> <IRanges>  <Rle> | <integer>
#>   [1]        1      1-49      * |         1
#>   [2]        1    50-100      * |         2
#>   [3]        1   101-150      * |         1
#>   -------
#>   seqinfo: 1 sequence from an unspecified genome; no seqlengths
```

<sup>Created on 2020-06-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: cool. never realize you could convert a coverage object to GRanges

Answer (score 1):

You can use GenomicRanges, first we create the GRanges object:

```
library(GenomicRanges)
gr = GRanges(seqnames=c(1,1),IRanges(start=c(1,50),end=c(100,150)))
```

Now you calculate the coverage which returns you an rle object:

```
COV = coverage(gr)
class(COV)

[1] "SimpleRleList"
attr(,"package")
[1] "IRanges"
```

What this tells you is for "1", there are 49 runs of 1, 51 runs of 2 and 50 runs of 1. which is more or less what you need, except you need to have it in a data.frame formt.

```
COV
RleList of length 1
$`1`
integer-Rle of length 150 with 3 runs
  Lengths: 49 51 50
  Values :  1  2  1
```

To manipulate this, it's better we write a function:

```
COV2bg = function(cov_obj){

  allchr = lapply(names(cov_obj),function(i){
              ends = cumsum(cov_obj[[i]]@lengths)
              GRanges(
                  seqnames=i,
                  IRanges(start=c(1,ends[-length(ends)]),end=ends),
                  value = cov_obj[[i]]@values
                   )
              })

 Reduce(c,allchr)
}
```

Then it's a matter of applying it onto the rle object:

```
as.data.frame(COV2bg(COV))
  seqnames start end width strand value
1        1     1  49    49      *     1
2        1    49 100    52      *     2
3        1   100 150    51      *     1
```